# Specify java version in scala-cli scala file

Tags: scala, scala-cli

`scala-cli` can use a specific java version using `--jvm adopt:11` cli option like:

`scala-cli compile . --jvm adopt:11`

There's a `java-home` directive in `scala-cli` that can be specified in a scala file.

e.g

```scala
// Test.scala
//> using java-home "/Users/Me/jdks/11"
//> using scala "3.2.0"
```

Is there a `jvm` directive that can be used to specify the JVM version directly in the scala file instead of scala-cli command option?

e.g

```scala
// Test.scala
//> using jvm "adopt:11" -- is there a way to do this?
//> using scala "3.2.0"
```

[scala-cli --jvm option](https://scala-cli.virtuslab.org/docs/reference/cli-options#--jvm)

[scala-cli java-home directive](https://scala-cli.virtuslab.org/docs/reference/directives#java-home)

Comment: apparently not? there's an issue on it at https://github.com/VirtusLab/scala-cli/issues/1337

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is now included in scala-cli v0.1.17.

https://github.com/VirtusLab/scala-cli/releases/tag/v0.1.17

```
//> using jvm "adopt:11"
```